# Meal ordering system and associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm doing meal ordering system in Rails, I made model for User, Restaurant, Meal and Order and I don't know which associations should I use to connect all these models together. For now my models looks like this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :orders
  has_many :restaurants, through: :orders
end

class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :restaurant
end

class Meal < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :restaurant
end

class Restaurant < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :orders
  has_many :meals
  has_many :users, through: :orders
end
```

Now when I'm using form to order some meal and save this order in the database I'm getting error in log:

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"+pwoJ/82k/2SiS7z4X4nVHyaKCMMfWCECQe6TufnkpNaW9PEgvlwxlf3skAH2QQupSLIoe81Z/I0CleL/m9cjw==", "orders"=>{"restaurant_id"=>"2", "meal_id"=>"2", "suggestions"=>""}, "commit"=>"Place your order"}
 Unpermitted parameters: restaurant_id, meal_id
    (0.1ms)  begin transaction
    (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
 Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
 Completed 302 Found in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

My order controller looks like this:

```
 class OrdersController < ApplicationController

   def new
     @order = Order.new
   end

   def create
     @order = Order.new(order_params)
     if @order.save
       redirect_to root_path
       flash[:success] = "Your order has been added"
     else
       flash[:danger] = "Error"
       redirect_to root_path
     end
   end

   private

   def order_params
     params.require(:orders).permit(:restaurant, :meal, :suggestions)
   end
 end
```

When I change def order_params to:

```
 params.require(:orders).permit(:restaurant_id, :meal_id, :suggestions)
```

I'm getting

```
 unknown attribute 'restaurant_id' for Order.
```

I assume that it's bad associations fault, can anyone help me?

*** UPDATE ***

Now I'm getting error in my log when I'm trying to save order:

```
 Started POST "/new_order" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-12-19 11:18:50 +0100
 Processing by OrdersController#create as HTML
   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"nnDqY0FVzUslTJ1VoL57vnlO6aSTLcVuenT1GJwloJ8+txGAPJoucOAyAeZGGVjEoPYJJnBlwhhHeRjdha1ugw==", "orders"=>{"restaurant_id"=>"4", "meal_id"=>"26", "suggestions"=>""}, "commit"=>"Place your order"}
    (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   Restaurant Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "restaurants".* FROM "restaurants" WHERE "restaurants"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
    (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
 Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
 Completed 302 Found in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

*** Update 2 ***

When I change for `@order.save!` I get:

```
 Validation failed: User must exist
```

With `order.errors.inspect` I just get:

```
  (0.2ms)  rollback transaction
 No template found for OrdersController#create, rendering head :no_content
 Completed 204 No Content in 97ms (ActiveRecord: 1.8ms)
```

I'm using omniauth to sign in before user can order a meal and this is only way to sign up or sign in. When I created Order model I used `user:references`, you think this can be a reason?

Comment: do you have a column `restaurant_id` defined on your `db/schema.rb` for your `orders` table ?

Comment: Thanks @sa77 it helped with the error but still can't save order in DB. I updated my post.

Comment: use `save!` instead of `save` it will through exception with a validation error

Comment: this must be due to some validation error you have on your model.. do a `@order.errors.inspect` on your else block on create action.. to see the error on your development logs

Comment: @NikitaMisharin @sa77 thanks, I used `save!` and then I used `@order.errors.inspect`, I updated my post with errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said that you have a sign_in/sign_up, so I assume that you have a `current_user` in your controller.

In order to save your order you need to supply `user_id`, here is a one way to do it

```
def order_params
  params.require(:orders).permit(:restaurant, :meal, :suggestions)
    .merge(user_id: current_user.id)
end
```